# Rails: Remove white border from Pie Chart using Chartkick Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

Is there a way to remove the white border from the pie chart slices by adding an option to the library?

I've got a snippet of the code I used to create this chart.

```
<%= pie_chart monthly(current_user.events), colors: colors_group, width: "200px", height: "200px", library:{animation:{easing: 'easeOutQuad'}} %>
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `borderWidth` option to `0`:

```
<%= pie_chart monthly(current_user.events), colors: colors_group, width: "200px", height: "200px", library: {animation: {easing: 'easeOutQuad'}, elements: {arc: {borderWidth: 0}}} %>
```

You can find more options for Chart.js element configuration on their [docs page](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#elements).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Zoran! this was just what I needed!