# Vue: Remove white border from Pie Chart using Chartkick Gem

Tags: html, vue.js, charts, chartkick

Is there a way to remove the white border from the pie chart slices by adding an option to the library? I am looking for the Vue version of this answer: [Rails: Remove white border from Pie Chart using Chartkick Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916211/rails-remove-white-border-from-pie-chart-using-chartkick-gem/57825960#57825960)

Code I am using.

`<pie-chart :data="donutChartData" :donut="true" :colors="colorsData" :download="true" :library="{cutoutPercentage: 50}" ></pie-chart>`

Any ideas how to do that in Vue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer found:

"Following the vue-chartkick readme page it shows you can use the `v-bind:library` to pass values directly to the Charts.js library, so you can use the same structure as the rails answer."

This works for me in Vue now:

```
<pie-chart :data="donutChartData" :donut="true" :colors="colorsData" :download="true" :library="{animation: {easing: 'easeOutQuad'}, elements: {arc: {borderWidth: 0}}}" ></pie-chart>
```